# MySQL on Windows - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' - cannot connect from any host

Tags: mysql, root-access

I tried to update my Mysql instance to support remote access. I went to MySQL Administration UI and added % (any host) for user root and removed all other entries.

Now I cannot access MySQL as root from any machine including localhost. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: did you flush privilege? Try restarting the MySQL service. Sometime it helps solving many problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Stop MySQL server
- Restart it on the command line, skipping authorizations: `mysqld.exe --skip-grant-tables`
- Fix your permissions (add both a `localhost` and a `127.0.0.1` record for root to the mysql.user table)
- Stop MySQL server
- Start MySQL normally