# MySQL on Windows - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' after fresh install

Tags: mysql

I've installed the latest MySQL on Windows 10 Pro. I included the wizard steps to set up initial values and chose to set it up as a dev machine. I left everything to the default values. After installing and restarting the machine, there's no way to connect to the database it seems.

I get the `MySQL Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` error both in MySQL Workbench as well as the MySQL Shell.

I've tried to set `skip-grant-tables` in `my.ini` as that comes up in a lot of answers on here. When I set that and try to start the MySQL80 Service, it shuts itself down within seconds again.

I've also tried to start with `mysqld.exe --skip-grant-tables` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697746/2684660) but that gave me the error that it couldn't find `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data`. This folder indeed didn't exist, after making this folder myself and running `mysqld.exe --skip-grant-tables` again, 3 files were added to this folder but I'm immediately thrown back to my CMD shell and no mysqld.exe process is running.

To reiterate, this is a Windows 10 machine, answers about `sudo mysql` or `/etc/my.conf` are N/A unfortunately.

Workbench, MySQL Shell and CMD Prompt were all running as Administrator in the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "-p" and password "password"?

Comment: No I had my password manager generate a password and pasted that it. I'm using that password by typing it in the MySQL shell or in the case of Workbench I'm pasting it in.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled MySQL with legacy authentication and the weakest password it'll accept and now it works... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`